# Passing in JSON body

Tags: javascript, json, jestjs

I'm writing some unit tests and I'm receiving an error

```
'SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1'
```

I understand that this is because JSON.parse is already reading an object.  Here is an example of the code

```
foo.js

const bar = async (request)=>{
        let Id = request.Id;
        let Handle = request.Handle;
        request = JSON.parse(request.body);
        let requestMessage = request.Info;
        let subId = request.subId;
}
```

here is the test code

```
foo.test.js

describe('foo tests', ()=>{
  test('footest', ()=>{
    let req = {
      Id: 111,
      Handle: "handle",
      body: {"Info": "into", "subId": 1010}
    };

    return foo.bar(req)

  })
})
```

I'd like to know how I can create something to pass in as req that JSON.parse will accept so I can test the logic thats in the bar function

Comment: `JSON.stringify` it?

Comment: I tried passing it in with JSON.stringify but get the 'Unexpected token u' error

Comment: That's what you'd see if it was undefined; did you pass the result? Give a [mcve].

Comment: That error usually means you are trying to parse something that is already parsed.

Comment: Yes I've passed in the result.  Also not sure what is incomplete about this?  What more would help?

Comment: If it's already an object, it's a simple solution.  Don't parse it.  it's already an object

Comment: I think you missed the part where I'm testing code thus I'm creating the object to pass in.  That's not an option.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see.  Yeah I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` on the body.

```
describe('foo tests', ()=>{
  test('footest', ()=>{
    let req = {
      Id: 111,
      Handle: "handle",
      body: JSON.stringify({"Info": "into", "subId": 1010})
    };

    return foo.bar(req)

  })
})
```

---

An explanation of what's happening:

`JSON.parse()` is supposed to be used on a JSON-formatted string. You're not passing in a string though, you're passing in `{"Info": "into", "subId": 1010}`, which is an object. As a result, `Object.toString()` is being called.

`({}).toString()` returns `"[object Object]"`. So you're effectively calling `JSON.parse("[object Object]")`. Your error message is complaining that `"[object Object]"` is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: I thought you were referring to the entire req object which is what I had tried